# VBA function to return first value, wait, return second value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a function to delay an email alert sent by excel. Basically my strategy is to have the email alert be triggered when two different cells are 1 at the same time. To delay it, after the initial email the plan is to have a function that sets one of the values to 0 so it wont send a ton of emails successively. I'm not terribly familiar with VBA, but Microsoft's website said this is the syntax to delay. However, this function only returns the 1 and not the 0. Is there a way to fix this so that it returns a value of 0 if called, waits a specified amount of time, and then returns the 1 again before ending. Or would there be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

```
Public Function Delay_Alert() As Integer
    
    Delay_Alert = 0

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 10
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

    Delay_Alert = 1

End Function
```

Comment: Your function delays for 10 seconds for sure, but it does not return before that. To make function calls asynchronous, you need at least to use timer - I don't know, is this possible in VBA or not. For your scenario - why don't you just set one cell to zero before sending e-mail out? How you detect that cells are set to 1? All this is a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The literal answer to your question is as follows. The code doesn't work as intended because the value you set only returns after the function finishes. So it is functionally equivalent to

```
Public Function Delay_Alert() As Integer
    
    Dim ret as Integer
    ret = 0

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 10
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

    ret = 1
    return ret 

End Function
```

As you can see ret is only returned after it has been set the second time, nothing outside the function ever knows its been set the first time.

The broader question is more difficult to answer without more information. Crude solutions would be to put the delay in whatever function sends the email, or update the cells from the function as Avro suggests in the comments.

```
Public Function Delay_Alert() As Integer
    
    Cells(2,1).Value = 0

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 10
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

    Cells(2,1).Value = 1

End Function
```

But if you're having to put artificial measures in to stop your code becoming a spambot then the real answer is to fix that problem. If your happy it's not spamming then just send the emails as needed, I'm sure the operating system and servers can cope.

Edit:-
In response to the comment I suggest you add a Hysteresis to your trigger
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Control_systems

Sounds an interesting project!

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. The practical problem I'm trying to solve is to have an alert sent if a value I'm watching in an excel sheet of real time market data overnight is over certain bounds. So if it keeps going back an forth just over / under the bounds I'm going to wake up to 10,000 emails. My concern with the delay snippet in the email script is that the script will still be called n times and I'll get  the same n emails. I'll try just having the script set another cell to a value but I agree it is crude to only have it be a certain cell and I don't know enough to get around that.